# Merkle tree 2nd preimage attack defense - prepending a specific byte value

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, merkle-tree

from https://github.com/fmerg/pymerkle

```
 Defense against second-preimage attack consists in the following security measures:
    - Before computing the hash of a leaf, prepend the corresponding record with 0x00
    - Before computing the hash of any interior node, prepend both of its parents' hashes with 0x01
```

(I understand that 0x00 and 0x01 are just "specific byte values" and they could be anything)

Why does this work?

Can't an attacker theoretically find a leaf hash of a forged content that begins with 0x00 ?

What good does prepending the parent's hash nodes do ?

Comment: I would strongly advice to check if [this Q/A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2106/1172) doesn't answer your question. If not, please create a post at [crypto.se] (and describe why the previous Q/A doesn't answer your question). If you do post there, then delete this post (after copying your content using [edit] :) ), no cross posting please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about cryptography, not programming.

Comment: Hello @MaartenBodewes I disagree with the conclusion: a merkle tree is a data structure like could be a binary tree or red black tree or many more.
In my opinion it's very helpful to understand why this structure inner workings exposes a vulnerability in some scenarios.
BTW I actually found the answer from that time ,but I also forgot it :D I need to find the notes from that time to re-answer the question

Comment: If you could word your doubts into a new question then I would be happy to upvote your question at [crypto.se].